# CefSharp Search Engine Implamentation

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I am working on a cefsharp based browser and i am trying to implement a search engine into the browser, but the code I have tried docent work, it doesn't really have any errors but when i star the project and type something i the text field nothing happens and it dosent load the search engine i entered into the code, the only time the textbox loads anything is when a url is typed.

This is the code used in the browser that docent work

```
    private void LoadUrl(string url)
    {
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        {
            WebUI.Load(url);
        }
        else
        {
            var searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(url);

            WebUI.Load(searchUrl);
        }
    }
```

i have also tried

```
        void LoadURl(String url)
        {
            if (url.StartsWith("http"))
            {
                WebUI.Load(url);
            }
            else
            {
            WebUI.Load(url);
            }
        }
```

i was also suggested to try

```
    private void LoadUrl(string url)
    {
        if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        {
            WebUI.LoadUrl(url);
        }
        else
        {
            var searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(url);

            WebUI.LoadUrl(searchUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have here really few Information on how your code works. But what I notice is that you use `WebUtility.HtmlEncode` for the search query. `WebUtility` has also a `WebUtility.UrlEncode` Method, that how I understand your question makes more sense it the context. This is the documentation for the method: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode

Comment: I dent seem to understand?

Comment: At the line `var searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + WebUtility.HtmlEncode(url);` replace the `HtmlEncode` with `UrlEncode`. I don't know if that changes something but that would be the right method when I understand your code right.

Comment: Alright, i did what you said but it still doesn't work, like I did mention there are no errors so I don't understand why it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The Url you are generating is invalid. You need to use `Uri.EscapeDataString` to convert the url param into a string that can be appended to a url.

```cs
// For this example we check if a well formed absolute Uri was provided
// and load that Url, all others will be loaded using the search engine
// e.g. https://github.com will load directly, attempting to load
// github.com will load the search engine with github.com as the query.
// 
if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
{
    chromiumWebBrowser.LoadUrl(url);
}
else
{
    var searchUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(url);

    chromiumWebBrowser.LoadUrl(searchUrl);
}
```

> nothing happens and it dosent load the search engine

You need to subscribe to the [LoadError](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/107.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_IChromiumWebBrowserBase_LoadError.htm) event to get actual error messages. It's up to you to display errors to the user. The following is a basic example:

```cs
chromiumWebBrowser.LoadError += OnChromiumWebBrowserLoadError;

private void OnChromiumWebBrowserLoadError(object sender, LoadErrorEventArgs e)
{
    //Actions that trigger a download will raise an aborted error.
    //Aborted is generally safe to ignore
    if (e.ErrorCode == CefErrorCode.Aborted)
    {
        return;
    }

    var errorHtml = string.Format("<html><body><h2>Failed to load URL {0} with error {1} ({2}).</h2></body></html>",
                                      e.FailedUrl, e.ErrorText, e.ErrorCode);

    _ = e.Browser.SetMainFrameDocumentContentAsync(errorHtml);
}
```

For testing purposes you can also copy and paste the `searchUrl` string you've generated and try loading it in `Chrome` to see what happens, you should also get an error.

Comment: one question, where do implement the code, in my main form search box or search button or in my address changed method.

Comment: I've updated the code example to load absolute Uri's directly, all others will be loaded using as queries to the search engine. This should better demo the behaviour for example purposes. To duplicate the behaviour of say the google url bar you'll need to write much more complex to determine what should be considered a search.

Comment: I really don't know how, i have tried to implement all i know to the best of my ability, would it help if i showed you all my main form code.

Comment: There's a working example now available at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/BrowserForm.cs#L189 clone the project and run it for yourself.